# How to put landmarks per floor of the building?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, network-dataset

If I want to route from RoomA of floor level 5 to RoomB of floor level 1 inside the same building. How to add direction confirmation landmarks with tolerance buffer 1.5 that will not conflict the landmark points per level?

Below with the sample direction, has a "Pass by **PA**" which is not a landmark from level 5.

Sample direction:

1: Start at DIRECTOR

2: Go southeast on I3 L05 Corridor

```
2.1: Pass by EXEC DIRECTOR. It will be on the left
2.2: Pass by DIRECTOR. It will be on the right
2.3: Pass by DEPUTY DIRECTOR. It will be on the right
```

3: Turn left to stay on I3 L05 Corridor

```
3.1: Pass by **PA**. It will be on the right
3.2: Pass by SENIOR MANAGER. It will be on the right
3.3: Pass by SENIOR MANAGER. It will be on the left
3.4: Pass by SENIOR MANAGER. It will be on the right
3.5: Pass by DEPUTY DIRECTOR. It will be on the left
```

4: Turn right to stay on I3 L05 Corridor

...

end

Comment: What happened when you tried creating and routing through such a network dataset?

Comment: landmarks from level 4 is shown from the route line of level 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is currently resolve. The work around was to customise the landmark data returned to have floorID then just filtered out by our arcgis nodejs middle-ware.

Comment: It is good that you've resolved your problem, but to help others, who have a similar problem, in the future it would be good if you could add some extra detail about your workaround